# I need to replicate the image

Tags: java

So this program needs to do a few things with the image. I started writing method called replicate and what it needs to do is to take in num1 and num2, and then duplicate the image left-right num1 times, and then replicate the picture num2 times top to bottom. So like the same a small image would act as desktop wallpaper, it's repeat itself. I am not allowed to use image buffer. thank you

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class ImageTool {

    // THIS METHOD MAY BE CALLED, BUT MUST NOT BE MODIFIED!
    //
    public static int[][] readGrayscaleImage(String filename) {
        int [][] result = null;
        try {
            File imageFile = new File(filename);
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(imageFile);
            int height = image.getHeight();
            int width  = image.getWidth();
            result = new int[height][width];
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                    int rgb = image.getRGB(x, y);
                    result[y][x] = rgb & 0xff;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.err.println("Problems reading file named " + filename);
            System.exit(1);
        }
        return result;
    }


    // THIS METHOD MAY BE CALLED, BUT MUST NOT BE MODIFIED!
    //
    public static void writeGrayscaleImage(String filename, int[][] array) {
        int width = array[0].length;
        int height = array.length;

        try {
            BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height,
                BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                    int rgb = array[y][x];
                    rgb |= rgb << 8;
                    rgb |= rgb << 16;
                    image.setRGB(x, y, rgb);
                }
            }
            File imageFile = new File(filename);
            ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", imageFile);
        }
        catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.err.println("Problems writing file named " + filename);
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    public static void main (String [] args) {
        if (args.length < 1) {
            System.out.println("Invalid program execution");
            System.out.println("Please provide command");
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        if (args[0].equals("--dump")){
            String fileName = args[1];
            int [][] image = readGrayscaleImage(fileName);
            print2dArray(image);
        } else if (args[0].equals("--reflectV")){
            String fileName = args[1];
            int [][] image = readGrayscaleImage(fileName);
            int [][] reflected = reflectV(image);
            String outputFilename = args[2];
            writeGrayscaleImage(outputFilename, reflected);
        } else if (args[0].equals("--reflectH")){
            String fileName = args[1];
            int [][] image = readGrayscaleImage(fileName);
            int [][] reflected = reflectH(image);
            String outputFilename = args[2];
            writeGrayscaleImage(outputFilename, reflected);
        } else if (args[0].equals("--ascii")){
            String fileName=args[1];
            int [][] image = readGrayscaleImage(fileName);
            ascii(image);
        } else if (args[0].equals("--replicate")) {
            String fileName = args[2];
            int [][] image = readGrayscaleImage(fileName);
            double factor = args[0];
            String outputFilename = args[3];
            writeGrayscaleImage(outputFilename, reflected);
        }

    }

    public static void replicate(double num1, double num2, int[][]arr) {
        double length = num1 * arr.length;
        double height = num2 * arr[0].length;
        int[][]newArr = new int[length][height];
            for(int i = 0; i <= newArr.length; i++){
                for(int j = 0; j <= arr.length; j++){
                newArr[i][j]=arr[i][j];

                }
            }

    }

    public static void ascii (int[][]arr) {
        int rows = arr.length;
        int cols = arr[0].length;

        for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++){
                if(arr[i][j] >= 0 && arr[i][j] <= 25){
                System.out.print("M");
                } else if(arr[i][j]>=26 && arr[i][j] <=50){
                System.out.print("$");
                } else if(arr[i][j]>=51 && arr[i][j] <= 76){
                System.out.print("0");
                } else if(arr[i][j]>=77 && arr[i][j] <=102){
                System.out.print("|");
                } else if(arr[i][j]>=103 && arr[i][j]<=127){
                System.out.print("*");
                } else if (arr[i][j]>=128 && arr[i][j]<=152){
                System.out.print(":");
                } else if (arr[i][j]>=153 && arr[i][j]<=178){
                System.out.print("=");
                } else if (arr[i][j]>=179 && arr[i][j]<=204){
                System.out.print("\'");
                } else if (arr[i][j]>=205 && arr[i][j]<=230){
                System.out.print(".");
                } else if (arr[i][j]>=231 && arr[i][j]<=255){
                System.out.print(" ");
                }
            } 

            System.out.println();
        }

    }


    public static void print2dArray(int[][] arr) {
        for (int i = 0; i <arr.length; i++){
            //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr[i]));
            for (int j = 0; j< arr[i].length; j++){
                System.out.format("%3d, " , arr[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static int [][] reflectV (int [][] arr) {
        int rows = arr.length;
        int cols = arr[0].length;
        int [][] reflected = new int[rows][cols];
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            reflected [i][j] = arr[i][cols-j-1];
            }
        }
        //go through arr and reverse values in each row

        return reflected;
    }

    public static int [][] reflectH (int [][] arr) {
        int rows = arr.length;
        int cols = arr[0].length;
        int [][] reflected = new int[rows][cols];
        for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
            reflected [j][i] = arr[cols-j-1][i];
            }
        }
        //go through arr and reverse values in each row

        return reflected;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please post only the relevant code snippet next time. It would be much more readable.

Answer (score 0):

This should be the solution:

```
public static int[][] replicate(double num1, double num2, int[][]arr) {
    double length = num1 * arr.length;
    double height = num2 * arr[0].length;
    int[][]newArr = new int[(int) length][(int) height];
    for(int i = 0; i < newArr.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < newArr[i].length; j++){
            newArr[i][j]=arr[i % arr.length][j % arr[0].length];
        }
    }
    return newArr;
}
```

Test input:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

The method calculates the output array as follows (`num1=1.8d` and `num2=1.8d`):

```
1 2 3 1 2
4 5 6 4 5
7 8 9 7 8
1 2 3 1 2
4 5 6 4 5
```

Please note that I have changed the signature of the method. It now returns the resulting array.